# Checking if there exists a string of directions that always leads to same vertex

Tags: c++, graph, computer-science

There is a graph with ***n*** vertices. Each one has 4 edges, one for each side of the world. All of them are directed. I have to write a program that checks if there exists a string of directions that always leads to same vertex, no matter where you start.
For example:

[example 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q0fRN.png)

If you go S W S you always will be in 3.

[example 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/On0Lz.png)

Such string of directions doesn't exist.

I have an idea how to do it but I would need a bool array with size ***2^n***. However, program has to work for ***n*** up to size 1000.
What's the best way to do it?

Comment: You should show us your `2^n` solution so you have a place to start!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sort of string you're describing is called a [synchronizing word](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synchronizing_word). If you are just trying to test whether such a word exists, there's a polynomial-time algorithm [described in these lecture slides](http://drona.csa.iisc.ernet.in/~deepakd/atc-2011/Raghu-DFA%20Synchronization.pdf). Intuitively, for each pair of nodes u and v, you build a new graph where the start node is the pair {u, v}. Each node has a transition defined on each character c to the set {t(c, u), t(c, v)}, where t(c, u) represents the node transitioned to by reading character c in state u. You can expand out this graph using DFS or BFS. The original graph has a synchronizing word if and only if for each pair of nodes {u, v}, the above process produces a graph that has a path from {u, v} to some singleton node.

If you search online, you can find all sorts of other readings on this topic. Hopefully the terminology and the above links can help get you started!